# Solving a recurrence relation with the characteristic equation

Tags: math, recurrence

I have some trouble solving this due to not seeing the steps to be able to feed it into the characteristic equation.

T(n) = 4T(n-2) +n + n^2 * 2^n;   T(0)=0; T(1)=1

I don't understand the steps to transform this into the (R-x)(R-y) form.
I know that i should transform it into the tn - 4T(n-2) - n - n^2 * 2^n = 0 but somewhere here i get lost. Can someone give me a hint (not solve it, from that i won't learn anything)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve an inhomogeneous (that is, the right hand side is not 0) recurrence relation, you solve the homogeneous case, and then find a particular solution. Thus, find the solution to `T(n) - 4T(n-2) = 0` and then utilize the [method of undetermined coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_undetermined_coefficients) to calculate a general solution.

Comment: Did not really understand the method of undetermined coefficients but the assignment clearly says that i don't have to solve for the constants, i have got T(n) - 4T(n-2) down to (r+2)(r-2) which in it's turn means tn = A(-2)^n + B(2)^n. How do do add my constants without solving

Answer (score 1):

That's because you can't transform it into (R-x)(R-y) form. It's not even a linear relation, so the usual methods don't help.

As for how I'd approach it, you should notice that `T(n)` depends only on `T(n-2)`. Therefore the even and odd values are independent. So try solving it for only even indices first.

If you let `T(2k) = F(k)` then you have
`F(k) = 4F(k-1) + 4k^2*4^k`

Hopefully that's enough to start.